# Issue with redirection in IIS?

Tags: iis

I have the following rule in IIS

```
     <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="apex" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:8080/ords/f?p=1" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This rule works fine and redirects URL's from

- **www.example.com/apex**

to

- **www.example.com:8080/ords/f?p=1**

I would like to get an URL without the port 8080 in it. So, when I change the rule type to Rewrite. It doesn't work any more. It ommits the port and I'm getting the error : 404 - File or directory not found

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.
Regards,

Comment: Mistake 3 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting 404.4. If you didn't enabled detailed error message for your website. Then you will get 404  File or directory not found.

Please install failed request tracing
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47333.

Then go to IIS manager->server node->application request routing cache->server proxy setting->enable proxy.